# Move up and down depending on the position of the mouse when it clicks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little dilemma. I'm develop a game and I need to do something that I do not understand. I have an object that moves up and down with this script:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (canClick)
    {
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0f, moveVertical, 0f);
        Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement * speed;
        Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3
        (
            -7.5f,
            Mathf.Clamp(Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax),
            0.0f
        );
    }
}
```

Now I want to do that when I click Mouse (0), the object moves upwards if Mouse.y> 0 and respectively down if Mouse.y position <0

```
    private void Update()
{
    Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (mouse.y > 0f)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How to do the same code as FixedUpdate, run it in Update, but do the checks. And already moving in dependence on Mouse.y.

Comment: Do you mean if the mouse is above the object? of i mouse is above center of screen?

Comment: so the screen separates it in two, and when I click up, it moves up and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the WorldSpace mouse positions Y to your GameObjects Y

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 movement;
        if (mouse.y > Tucan.transform.position.y)
        {
            movement = Vector3.up;
        }
        else
        {
            movement = Vector3.down;
        }


        Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement * speed;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you wanted a split screen solution

> so the screen separates it in two, and when I click up, it moves up
>   and vice versa

```
void Update()
{
    var mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    mouse.y -= Screen.height / 2;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 movement;
        if (mouse.y > 0)
        {
            movement = Vector3.up;
        }
        else
        {
            movement = Vector3.down;
        }


        Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work, i reproduces it myself first before posting

Comment: But i will make an edit to make it a split screen thing instead!

Comment: I do not know why, but it really does not move the object

Comment: I changed and speed was higher, nothing at all

Comment: Strange! Is Tucan assigned to the script? Can you add some Debug.Log() to check whats going on

Comment: I do not understand what's going on, everything's fixed. It has to go, but it does not work. I put and debug.log, it shows me that it is coming in and doing the transformations, but nothing happens. Wtf :D

Comment: 'Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (mouse.y > 0f)
            {
                if (Tucan.transform.position.y < boundary.yMax)
                    Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * maxSpeed, ForceMode2D.Force);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Tucan.transform.position.y > boundary.yMin)
                    Tucan.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.down * maxSpeed, ForceMode2D.Force);
            }
        }'

Comment: Dont know what boundary values are, so i removed those ifs and put 255 instead of maxSpeed and my object moves